# who to create multiple instance of JBOSS Fuse 6.1

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

i want to install multiple instance of jboss fuse and then integrate each jboss instance with different environment .

eg suppose we have 6 SIT env then we need 6 different jboss fuse to be connected.
and suppose we have 10 different unix user on one server and jboss fuse is install on this server now how we can install fuse on each unix user.

can we create jboss domain same as web-logic domain?

Currently we have downloaded zip file of jboss fuse from red-hat site and unzip this file and do configuration changes per environment that is we unzip file in 6 different users and integrated to SIT env.

what is standard way of doing this?

Comment: Jboss Fuse and Weblogic are two separate types of containers. One is an integration ESB container and the other is a JEE container. Are you sure you are not supposed to use JBoss EAP 6 instead which is the JBoss JEE6 container?

Comment: we will going to use JBOSS EAP6.1, JBOSS AMQ 6.1 and this JBOSS is going to integrate SIT Environment which is deployed in weblogic .

Comment: I would recommend EAP 6.4 and you can use the domain mode for your weblogic like setup.

Comment: we cannot use EAP6.4 as customer want fuse , amq and eap on 6.1 verison
forget about web-logic , we have install jboss on one Linux server and we have 10 user account on this server now we want to install fuse on this all account . Now let me know how we can do this

Comment: Asking how to install and configure multiple software tools. This is too broad of a topic to cover.

Comment: I recommend you work with Red Hat support for specific documentation and guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is

> Fabric

with the help **Fabric** we can support multiple environment without any issue.

.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instances

for that you would require to change in etc\system.properties
Change port for below attribute

```
org.osgi.service.http.port=<Port> #Every Instance should have different port
```

If you accessing it via putty. It is better to change sshPort as well to prevent the conflict. in etc\org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg

```
sshPort=8107
```

Last thing you would require to change is RMI Server Port in etc\org.apache.karaf.management.cfg for each instance.

```
rmiServerPort = 44444
```

Comment: we already do this but still facing some issue as internally JBOSS use some ports which we cannot change. So now we are using fabric concept.